# How would I divide one list/array by another?

Tags: python

For example, I have gathered a list of the lowest numbers of a list and I need to divide them by each other but repeat themselves down the list similar to a Cartesian product.

Not exact code below, but similar. Exact code would just be confusing if I posted it.

```
lowestnumbers = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
highestnumbers = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for matchhigh in highestnumbers:
    print (matchhigh)
for matchlow in lowestnumbers:
    print (matchlow)
    percentage = (matchlow / matchhigh - 1.0)
    print (percentage)
```

When I've done this, it repeats the last number of from "matchhigh" and repeatedly divides itself by that last number.

I need something to do something along the lines of below and I'm completely lost.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,2,1]
for number in list1
     answer = number / list2
     print = answer
```

Desired Output:

```
0.3333333333333333
0.5
1
0.6666666666666667
1
2
1
1.5
3
```

Please let me know if there is a solution to the issue I am having, it's driving me insane.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen when you divide a number by a list. Please show your desired output.

Comment: `itertools.product()` might help but it's not clear exactly what you want

Comment: Sorry guys. I've been up all night trying to fix this, lacking some sleep here. Just edited post now. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested loop will do:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [3,2,1]
>>> for x1 in list1:
...     for x2 in list2:
...         print(x1/x2)  # Python3
...         print(float(x1)/x2)  # Python2
```

Or [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for x1, x2 in product(list1, list2):
...     print(x1/x2)  # Python3
...     print(float(x1)/x2)  # Python2

0.3333333333333333
0.5
1.0
0.6666666666666666
1.0
2.0
1.0
1.5
3.0
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you, I knew it would be something simple. Now time to find out how to split this list accordingly, should be easy from here on out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

div_list = [a / b for a, b in product(list1, list2)]

print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in div_list))
```